# External library (dompdf) in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pdf, dompdf

I'm developing a plugin to handle stock, clients, bills, etc.

There is a moment when I need to create a bill in pdf for a client, and to save it on the server.

I've decided to use dompdf library, that lets you to make PDF with custom html.

I've added all files from the library on my plugin dir, and I've tried with the basic example of usage

```
// EXAMPLE TAKEN FROM https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

require_once(GESTION_ODC_DIR . 'dompdf\autoload.inc.php');

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

But the file created has only 18 lines. Could you help me to identify the problem?:

[image: Screenshot of the pdf content]

I edit the question, because I've discovered that adding

```
ob_clean();
```

before dompdf functions, it works perfectly, but I think it's not a real solution. Any idea?

Comment: Actually, that is probably is the solution. WordPress is generating header content and putting it into the output buffer before you get to the point of generating the PDF. Clearing the buffer removes that content so PDF generation can proceed unhindered (otherwise the cited HTML would be inserted into the PDF source).

Comment: I don't know WordPress well enough to tell you how to do this, but what you would want is some kind of alternate view template for PDF generation so that the HTML-oriented template doesn't generate unnecessary content.

Comment: I think the ob_clean() is the way to go. I did once a PDF invoice creation function with mpdf (and Wordpress), and its tutorial included this (actually they suggested using ob_end_clean()). After this I manually set the headers of the file for mailing.